# Image processing techniques to stand out white tape on the floor with opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have the following image:

[image: Original]

And I'd like to obtain a thresholded image where only the tape is white, and the whole background is black.. so far I've tried this:

```
Mat image = Highgui.imread("C:/bezier/0.JPG");
Mat byn = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, byn, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Mat thresh = new Mat();

// apply filters
Imgproc.blur(byn, byn, new Size(2, 2));
Imgproc.threshold(byn, thresh, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY+Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
Imgproc.erode(thresh, thresh, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(4, 4)));
```

But I obtain this image, that is far away from what I want:

[image: Thresholded image]

The tape would be always of the same color (white) and width (about 2cm), any idea? Thanks

Comment: Will the (poor) contrast and the translucence of the tape be the same in the production setting?

Comment: Nope @fvu, In production I think I'll use a retroreflective tape to boost the contrast and maybe with an IR camera (less likely)

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what you know:

- The tape has a lower contrast
- The tape is lighter than the background

If you know the scale of the picture, you can run adaptive thresholds on two levels. Let's say that the width of the tape is 100 pixels:

1. Reject a pixel that has brightness outside of +/- x from the average brightness in the 50x50 (maybe smaller, but not larger) window surrounding it AND
2. Reject a pixel that has brightness smaller than y + the average brightness in the 100x100(maybe larger, but not smaller) window surrounding it.

You should also experiment a bit, trying both mean and median as definitions of "average" for each threshold.

From there on you should have a much better-defined image, and you can remove all but the largest contour (presumably the trail)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not taking advantage of the fact that the tape is white (and the floor is in a shade of brown).

Rather than converting to grayscale with `cvtColor(src, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` try using a custom operation that penalizes saturation... Maybe something like converting to HSV and let `G = V * (1-S)`.